# Memory Leak in Fragment due to infinite loop under lifecycle scope of coroutine

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, coroutine

**Description:**
I've encountered an issue in my application where the performance degrades over time and appears to be related to a potential memory leak. Here's the setup:

**Scenario:**

The main screen features two fragments: one for simulating vehicle speed with an infinite loop and another for various functionalities.
The left side screen, containing the fragments, remains on the main thread and is always open.
On the right side of the screen, a navigation graph loads six other fragments.

**Problem:**
After the application has been running for an extended period, I've noticed a gradual slowdown in the overall performance.
My concern is that the left side screen, with its infinite loop for simulating vehicle speed, might be causing this issue and potentially leading to a memory leak.

**Request:**
I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or best practices to tackle this problem. Specifically:

Recommendations for handling an infinite loop within a fragment to avoid performance degradation and memory leaks.
Tips on optimizing the main thread's performance, especially when one side of the screen is always open.
Strategies to ensure efficient memory usage and prevent memory leaks when using navigation graphs and loading multiple fragments.
I'm eager to learn from your expertise and implement the necessary changes to maintain a smooth user experience without compromising the application's performance.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**My XML Code is below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rvBottomMenu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineCenter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_speed" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rvBottomMenu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/guide_begin_main"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnExpand"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_expand_shrink"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnMic"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_mic"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clViewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_border_main"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineCenter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rvBottomMenu">
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_fragments" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvBottomMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:itemIconSize="@dimen/tab_icon_size"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#EF0C4C"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:listitem="@layout/items_bottom_menu"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**Kotlin Code is below**

```
  @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
      private suspend fun readSpeed(){
           var speedValue = 1
                while (true){
                    speedValue += 1
                    binding.tvSpeed.text = ""
                    binding.tvSpeed.text = speedValue.toString()
                    delay(200)
                    if (speedValue == 140){
                        speedValue = 1
                    }
                    if (speedValue <= 45){
                        val newDrawable = getApplicationContext().resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.green_bg, null)
                        val transitionDrawable = TransitionDrawable(arrayOf(binding.clSpeedometerMain.background, newDrawable))
                        binding.clSpeedometerMain.background = transitionDrawable
                        transitionDrawable.startTransition(3000)
    
                    }else if(speedValue in 46 .. 80){
                        val newDrawable = getApplicationContext().resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.city_bg, null)
                        val transitionDrawable = TransitionDrawable(arrayOf(binding.clSpeedometerMain.background, newDrawable))
                        binding.clSpeedometerMain.background = transitionDrawable
                        transitionDrawable.startTransition(3000)
                    }else {
                        val newDrawable = getApplicationContext().resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.red_bg, null)
                        val transitionDrawable = TransitionDrawable(arrayOf(binding.clSpeedometerMain.background, newDrawable))
                        binding.clSpeedometerMain.background = transitionDrawable
                        transitionDrawable.startTransition(3000)                }
    
                }
        }
```

**And the above method is calling as below**

```
private fun getSpeed() {
        this.lifecycleScope.launch(Main) {
            readSpeed()
        }
    }
```

**And the getSpeed() function is calling at onResume() callback of fragment.**

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    getSpeed()
}
```

Comment: check if [`LeakCanary`](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/) what is leaking

Answer (score 0):

As of now I solved this issue by just refreshing the fragment after each interval of certain time, and by clearing the cache of application programmatically.

> On refreshing the fragments, the lifecycle-scope is cancelling
> automatically, that preventing the memory leak, and the app is running as expexting. **but still looking for some best practices**.

**My code what I am using is below**

**In Vewmodel:**

```
 suspend fun clearCache(callback: (Int) -> Unit) {
        var cacheTime = 1
        while (true) {
            cacheTime += 1
            callback(cacheTime)
            delay(1000)
            if (cacheTime == 35) {
                cacheTime = 1
            }

        }
    }
```

**And in fragment class:**

```
this.lifecycleScope.launch(Main) {
            speedViewModel.clearCache { cacheTime ->
                clearCache(cacheTime)
            }
        }


private fun clearCache(cacheTime: Int) {
        if (cacheTime == 34) {    
            val fragmentId = findNavController().currentDestination?.id
            findNavController().popBackStack(fragmentId!!, true)
            findNavController().navigate(fragmentId)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are creating drawables for every loop. Avoid creating the same drawables, it will exhaust the heap memory. Rather, pull it out of while loop and create separate drawables.
2. As per @snachmsm's suggestion, use LeakCanary to see where memory is getting leaked.
3. Also, learn how to use [Android Studio profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler)

Do let us know if it helped improve the performance